# How to convert a numeric date vector into text date vector?

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I have a numeric vector corresponding to dates in the following format yyyymmdd, ie for December 24th, 2010 it is 20101224. How can I convert it into text format, i.e. in the following format 'mm-dd-yyyy'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really use `datetime` rather than convert to strings,

```
dates = datetime(20100124,'ConvertFrom','yyyymmdd')
```

The first input can be a numeric vector, assuming it's of the yyyymmdd format.

If you then want to specify a display format use,

```
dates.Format = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
```

If you really need them as strings you can then use,

```
dates = datestr(dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a `datestr` command which might be useful.  Example usage:

```
formatOut = 'mm-dd-yyyy';
datestr(now,formatOut)
```

For your date, you could convert the input number to a string, convert the string to a date and create a date string with the new format.

```
formatIn = 'yyyymmdd';
formatOut = 'mm-dd-yyyy';
inStr = num2str(20101224);    % Skip this step if already a number
outStr = datestr(datenum(inStr, formatIn), formatOut)
```